# How does Data maintain his personal hygiene?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

I'm assuming Data doesn't need to go *number 1* or *2*, but an android's *bioplast sheeting* (his skin) can and has been seen dirty on-screen (in *Star Trek: Nemesis*, B-4 was found quite dirty from dust/dirt).

How does Data keep himself appearing clean?

Comment: Why do you assume he is unable to take showers? As for internal care, Geordi is often seen performing maintenance on him.

Comment: Good question, not really assuming he can't, just if he did I guess. Perhaps some reason he did or did not use sonic showers to maintain his skin.

Comment: If questions like [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1241/where-does-human-waste-go-when-going-to-the-toilet-in-the-star-trek-universe), and [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8962/what-bodily-functions-work-in-vampires/8979#8979) can exist open, I don't see how this question is a Fail.

Comment: The difference for me is, his ability to take a bath is no different than anyone else's. He does not sweat, he does not have bacteria, so baring injury, a bath (or sonic shower) is a bath, whether he is an android or a person. I just don't see any particular value in asking how he bathes himself; because the obvious answer is "just like everyone else".

Comment: Hi Thaddeus, the question wasn't does he bathe or not, the question was how does he keep himself clean. I don't think it's fair to assume the answer is as obvious as "same as everyone else" when you've quite clearly pointed out "He does not sweat, he does not have bacteria" which is so obviously different from humanoid beings and his skin isn't living tissue...

Comment: I agree with Thaddeus, which is why I VTC.  He's water proof, all he would need to do is simply rinse his exterior off, the same as anyone else.

Comment: @Monty129 - to be fair, Starfleet vessels were not equipped with water showers by 2272 and replaced by sonic showers. Maybe sonic showers did something to his skin, who knows, hence the question?

Comment: My VTC was "Too Localized" rather than "Not Constructive"; The question seemed to me to a bit strange (and would only matter to the OP) due to similar reasons as what Thaddeus said...

Comment: His skin has consistently been depicted as stronger and more durable than human skin, why would something that's designed not to irritate human skin affect him?

Comment: @izkata 'too localized' can be subjective based on popularity of the context.  You'd have to be very localized to be _too_ localized with a Star Trek question here.  Now, count the comments and ask yourself if it's really _too_ localized ;)

Comment: If we used that mentality on all questions here, pretty much nothing would get answered. I see yours and Thaddeus points, but they don't override the fact no one has given supported facts that Data does clean himself the same way as everyone else. Which is ironic since VTC as "not constructive" says "We expect answers to be supported by facts, references" :)

Comment: I think it's time y'all take this to chat or meta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As there are **no legitimate case examples** in the canon stating that Data is incapable of using normal tools/methods for his personal hygiene, it is reasonable enough to suggest that he simply uses a sonic shower like the rest of his crew mates.  I can't find any reference which states that Data is somehow damaged or susceptible to some negative effect from sonic waves.  ***Even if this were the case***, there would always be the option for him to simply use water to remove said dirt/dust/grime.  From what I understand of Data's composition, he has a fully enclosed artificial integumentary system which, though it doesn't perfectly simulate human skin, does protect the parts of his internal framework.  Also, though Data is [not completely waterproof](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Devala_Lake), that wouldn't stop him from actually **washing the surface** of his skin if he kept any orifices sealed (just like we as humans should probably not take deep breaths underneath the water while take a bath).  In fact, there are several times in the series which show him fully capable of operating while wet, even when submerged.

*I'm not seeing any sparks shooting out of his ears here...*

[image: Oh Data... you so silly]

Now, the argument against his ability to use water might be that "there are no water showers/sources of water for cleanliness on the Enterprise!"  However, that would be a wrong assessment of the situation as well.  There are multiple examples throughout the franchise of [water being used as a method of hygiene](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Bath): Captain Archer had his infamous shower malfunction, the first scene of Neelix actually on Voyager was one in which he bathed water, captain Janeway had her own personal bathtub, etc, etc.  However, the one example that is most relevant would be the fact that [**Dianna Troi had a bathtub**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_%28Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation%29) in her quarters (which she was pictured as starting devolving into an amphibian in) on the Enterprise.  It wouldn't be to far of a stretch for Data to have one too if need be.

I hope this helped a little.  If Data used some other kind of device or method for keeping clean, there isn't any reference I can find that states so, and the evidence would seem to suggest that he is capable of using the exact same facilities that his biological counterparts use as well.

Comment: In ST: Insurrection, Deanna was giving Will a shave in her bathtub when Admiral Dougherty called (audio only, fortunately).

Comment: That image is from a really ridiculous scene, and according to the [ST:TNG episode Descent: Part 2](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/253.htm) Data was not "designed as a flotation device", and when he *"decided to go swimming"* and *"jumped out of the boat you sank straight to the bottom"*... *"It took almost two weeks to get the water out of [Data's] servos."* [IMDB even calls it a Goof](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120844/goofs?item=gf2175069)

Comment: @Xen2050: I agree, that scene was completely ridiculous.  That said, I'm sure someone as intelligent as Data (and who has shown willingness to modify himself in the past) would have been unlikely to leave such a glaring weakness (unable to swim) uncorrected after it was discovered.  He may have given himself a buoyancy system (and possibly improved waterproofing) following that incident.

Comment: @Jeff Good point, I just watched the Data & Lore & Dr.Soong episode where Lore had that interesting fingernail communicator/transporter button, probably a modification (unless he & Data just have a button under their fingernail for some reason?). Still, being modified after manufacture is not the same as having been designed that way, so at least technically the Insurrection writers or Data were wrong on semantics ;-)